# writing custom dropout layers in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
class MonteCarloDropout(tf.keras.layers.Dropout):
     def call(self, inputs):
        return super().call(inputs, training=True)
```

Following some tutorial, I tried to write my own dropout layer, but I noticed that I am unable to change training=False during prediction. Appreciate is somebody can provide some guidance on this. Thank you :)